# What's new with negative score of the questions?

Tags: support, voting

I've upvoted a question and got notification:

[image: notification]

Then I checked question score:

[image: total score] [image: detailed score]

So total is `-1` instead of `-2`. What is it, why is it made and how it works? Does it affect all users or new contributors only? How is user rating calculated in such cases?