# Bug in count of upvotes and downvotes

Tags: bug, voting

Yesterday, I noticed this particular answer had -1 count of votes and then I clicked on it to view the count of upvotes and downvotes it showed `+1 upvote and -2 downvotes`.

Now today, when I revisited this same answer today it is showing a total of 0 counts of votes and still, the total count of upvotes and downvotes is being displayed `+1 upvote and -2 downvotes`.

How is this possible? Is this some kind of bug or something else?

I have refreshed the page more than 10 times before asking this question here. I have tried reopening the tab also.

**Total count of votes**
[image: Screenshot 1]

**When viewed it is displaying this**

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390249/1288408 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334832/204841

Comment: Is this some kind of new update or change in the voting system? I am not so clear about this?

Comment: Well you could read the linked question and its answer to get "clear about this" ...

Comment: Yeah! Thanks, everyone I am clear about this now. I have gone through the links. I wasnt aware of this before and suddenly I ended up asking a question here about this new voting system with 2 downvotes :(

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I didn't downvote, but others might have because of lack of research. This came up at least 3 times before yesterday on Meta and Meta SO.

Comment: I did some research and found nothing maybe I was searching wrong. No worries but honestly I think that this question might keep on coming from other users as well as it is NEW and the users are not aware of it.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal yeah, no worries. It will stick around for 30 days at least, that should be enough time for others to find your post and with that find the actual duplicate. And as the votes here on meta have no effect on your rep, it is best advised to keep this post around and NOT delete it yourself. This post can act as a signpost.

Comment: I was not going to delete this post because of downvotes. No worries! :)